# How to have image inside svg background with radialGradient

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have svg element with some image inside it. I tried clipPath, but the results were not as expected

here's the code

```html
<svg width="5396" height="829" enable-background="new" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1427.7 219.34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<radialGradient id="headera" cx="-334.2" cy="-79.465" r="713.85" gradientTransform="matrix(.35196 -.0011319 .0010719 .334 127.5 106)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9d6173" offset="0"/>
<stop stop-color="#594b4f" offset="1"/>
</radialGradient>
<clipPath id="dodol">
<rect x="36.286" y="108.01" width="0" height="0" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#453030" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".052917"/>
<path d="m-535.38 77.813v6.0476c2.9078 113.15 92.911 174.65 152.71 167.82 169.93-23.912 248.91 44.042 387.75 45.474 56.339-1.17 204.04-22.034 204.04-22.034 78.053-5.4634 100.32 22.158 142.53 22.034 181.38-0.15553 205.7-119.12 449.25-127.14 104.33-1.7411 90.846-92.203 90.846-92.203z" fill="url(#headera)"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 .99999 535.38 -77.81)">
<rect x="36.286" y="108.01" width="0" height="0" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#453030" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".052917"/>
<path d="m-535.38 77.813v6.0476c2.9078 113.15 92.911 174.65 152.71 167.82 169.93-23.912 248.91 44.042 387.75 45.474 56.339-1.17 204.04-22.034 204.04-22.034 78.053-5.4634 100.32 22.158 142.53 22.034 181.38-0.15553 205.7-119.12 449.25-127.14 104.33-1.7411 90.846-92.203 90.846-92.203z" fill="url(#headera)"/>
</g>
<image clip-path="url(#dodol)" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet" width="643px" height="50%" x="250" y="20" xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png"/>
</svg>
```

the problem with the code is I can't resize the image as it should and some of the outgoing image that exceeds the svg element remains visible

what i want to achive is

- the svg shape appears as the background for the image inside it
- the image appereance clipped by svg shape
- I can adjust the position and size of the image

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure this is what you need. Please take a look.

The main idea is that you have to put the image inside the transformed group.

Also I've removed some useless elements (rects with width and height 0). Also instead of using the same path twice I'm reusing it with `<use>`

Yet another thing: I've changed the image size so that it keeps it's width/height ratio. It may not be what you want.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1427.7 219.34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<radialGradient id="headera" cx="-334.2" cy="-79.465" r="713.85" gradientTransform="matrix(.35196 -.0011319 .0010719 .334 127.5 106)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9d6173" offset="0"/>
<stop stop-color="#594b4f" offset="1"/>
</radialGradient>
<clipPath id="dodol">
<path id="thePath" d="m-535.38 77.813v6.0476c2.9078 113.15 92.911 174.65 152.71 167.82 169.93-23.912 248.91 44.042 387.75 45.474 56.339-1.17 204.04-22.034 204.04-22.034 78.053-5.4634 100.32 22.158 142.53 22.034 181.38-0.15553 205.7-119.12 449.25-127.14 104.33-1.7411 90.846-92.203 90.846-92.203z" />
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 .99999 535.38 -77.81)">

<use xlink:href="#thePath" fill="url(#headera)"/>

<image clip-path="url(#dodol)"  width="600" height="529" x="250" y="20" xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: in fact this is what i'm looking for. but the `width` and `height` doesnt work (image size still larger than it should be)  any idea?

Comment: What would the needed image size be?

Comment: let say the real image should have width="643px" and height="493px", in the browser test the image  become 2430px and the height 1863.

Comment: In your code you have the SVG's `width="5396"` and the `viewBox` width is 1427.7. This means that an image with a `width="643"` will be 643*5396/1427.7 = 2430.222. Do you need your image to be 643px wide?

Comment: hmm... if you dont mind can you explain me how to make the svg still have `width="5396"` but not affect the image so i can have real `width` and `height` for the `<img/>`

Comment: In this case the image's width should be 643*1427.7/5396 = 170.128. The image's height would be 493*219.34/829 = 130.44